# Unable to send metadata to s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file onto the S3 bucket using presignedURL and trying to send userId as the metadata. Even after trying different ways I am unable to receive the metadata with my object, the file gets uploaded as intented but the metadata field is blank.

```
async function getSignedUrl(userId) {
    // prepare the post request
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const fname = JSON.stringify({ app: fileInput.current.files[0].name });
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: fname,
      redirect: 'follow',
    };
    const apiURL = '......';
    const response = await fetch(apiURL, requestOptions);
    if (response.ok) {
      // prepare to upload file
      const result = await response.json();
      const { url } = result;
      const { key } = result.fields;
      const keyID = result.fields.AWSAccessKeyId;
      const secToken = result.fields['x-amz-security-token'];
      const { policy } = result.fields;
      const { signature } = result.fields;
      console.log(result.fields)
      uploadAPP(url, key, keyID, secToken, policy, signature, fileInput.current.files[0], userId);
    } else {
      alert(`HTTP-Error: ${response.status}`);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

```
  async function uploadAPP(url_, key_, keyID_, secToken_, policy_, signature_, appFile_, userId) {
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('key', key_);
    formdata.append('AWSAccessKeyId', keyID_);
    formdata.append('x-amz-security-token', secToken_);
    formdata.append('policy', policy_);
    formdata.append('signature', signature_);
    formdata.append('file', appFile_, key_);

    const requestOpts = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formdata,
      redirect: 'follow',
      headers: {
        'x-amz-meta-userId': userId,
      },
    };

    // upload file
    const response = await fetch(url_, requestOpts);
    if (response.ok) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setAlertOpen(true);
      fileInput.current.value = '';
    } else {
      alert(`HTTP-Error: ${response.status}`);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to do so"? What happens? Is there an error message? Please Edit your question and tell us more.

Comment: I have added more information regarding the same @JohnRotenstein